# send command to an already running screen session

Tags: gnu-screen, session, opensolaris

I have been trying to send commands to a running gnu screen session (4.00.03) in opensolaris, but cannot get it to run any commands through any combination of `screen -X`

Ok, I start a screen session with `screen -S test`, and then tried to with `screen -r -X "date"`to just show me the date, when I would reconnect to it. But neither an error message nor output in the screen happened. I tried with so many combinations, that I can't even remember.

Any hints on how to accomplish it?

The reason why I am doing this is, because I have a program, which does not come as a daemon, and I wish to start it in a screen session, so I can later on see what is going on.

Comment: it seems, as if this "command" that they are talking about in the man pages is meant for a screen command, like settings for the screen session itself. Rather than sending commands for the shell, which is opened in the screen session.
So, anyone an idea of how to make it happen with a bash script??

Comment: @Axon: Yes, -X sends screen commands, not shell commands, but screen has a command 'screen' which can open new screen windows.

Answer (score 19):

Actually it's quite simple. You can use the following:

```
screen -S sessionname -X stuff 'command'`echo -ne '\015'`
```

`echo -ne '\015'` emulates pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

NOTE: that 'stuff' is a screen command.
http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Stuff

Comment: Could you please specify what "stuff" represents? Is that a name...or command...or other parameters?

Comment: It works in fact, but I wouldn't say it's simply anyhow ;) This is something like passing keypressed events and passing newline to the screen. Isn't there just normal screen execute command...?

Comment: @Cecin: `stuff` is a screen command to 'stuff' a string into stdin

Comment: This is very good, but for some reason it doesn't work with "screen -RdS sessionname -X stuff 'ls -l'`echo -ne '\015'`", why?

Comment: this doesn't work for me... does not emulate enter key...

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the `^M` syntax. I.e.: `screen -S sessionname -X stuff "command^M"`

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like you want:

```
$ screen -S test -d -m -c /dev/null -- sh -c 'date; exec $SHELL'

-S test: name this session
-d -m: start screen detached
-c /dev/null: ignore ~/.screenrc (provide a different file or drop this option,
  as needed)
--: end of screen options
sh -c 'date; exec $SHELL': command for screen to run, note that if this command
  was just 'date' then screen would exit immediately.  if you don't want to exit
  screen after your command exits, then you might use:
    $ screen -S test -d -m -c /dev/null -- your command here
```

Or maybe you just want [dtach](http://dtach.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Running this results in nothing. No success or error messages, but `screen -list` shows no sessions are open.

Comment: This answer worked for me. The key was the -- to end the screen options.

Answer (score 2):

```
screen -S <session_name> -X screen [-t <title>] <shell_command> [<args>]
```

Open a new window (with title *title*) in an existing session named *session_name*, and execute *shell_command* (with optional arguments *args*)

Answer (score 2):

Like some of the comments on here, I was also unable to get this command to work at first, on Ubuntu Server 22.04. Here's what actually worked for me:

```
screen -S <sessionName> -p 0 -X stuff 'command^M'
```

The `-p 0` was what did it to select the first window, despite the `stuff` command claiming that it operates on "the current window", and the `^M` was a nicer alternative form of the `echo -ne '\015'`.

From: https://raymii.org/s/snippets/Sending_commands_or_input_to_a_screen_session.html

Comment: Worked great for my detached screen session!