# Move already running program into screen

Tags: unix, shell, gnu-screen, tmux

Is it possible to have a already started program move to `screen`/`tmux`? I'd like to have something like the following:

```
program;
^Z
screen;
fg;
```

I know the above won't work, but is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: It is *not a duplicate* of [that question](http://superuser.com/questions/116743/send-command-to-an-already-running-screen-session), as in this one, the user is already running the `program` and wants to suspend it (`^Z`), *then* move to a screen.

Comment: Yes exactly. The program is already running, but then I decide it's better to have it in a screen (so I can leave my PC). I don't care if it creates a new screen session or is added to an existing one …

Comment: If it's a non-interactive program, couldn't you just use `disown`?

Comment: This is a problem of moving a child process under another parent.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is under no circumstances simple to solve, but have a look at [reptyr](http://blog.nelhage.com/2011/01/reptyr-attach-a-running-process-to-a-new-terminal/). It can sometimes help you, especially if you don't care about noise printed in the original terminal & c. You'll might have to compile it yourself, although some distros, Gentoo for instance, package it.