# How can I send a command to two separate screen sessions simultaneously?

Tags: gnu-screen, terminal.app

I'm monitoring two measurement devices (usbserial1 and usbserial2) over RS232 (via an USB adapter). 
I do this in the following way:

1. I open two terminal windows.
2. In one window I write the following commands:

   mkdir one
   cd one
   screen -L /dev/tty.usbserial1 9600
3. In the other window I write:

   mkdir two
   cd two
   screen -L /dev/tty.usbserial2 115200

Now I want to send the `date` command to *both* the screen sessions at the same time.
How do I do that?
[This answer](https://superuser.com/questions/116743/send-command-to-an-already-running-screen-session) describes how I would do it for one session, but I want to do it for two sessions simultaneously.

Comment: What do you mean “simultaneously”?  By which I mean, why not do it for one session, and then, 5 milliseconds later, do it for the other session?

Comment: @Scott I want to do it simultaneously as this would synchronise the measurement devices. If I can do this with a fixed delay (e.g. 5 ms) this would also work for me, as I can later offset one datastream by the delay and still have synchronised data. How would I do this with a delay?

Comment: I was just thinking of a single command line that would `{send to screen 1}` **;** `{send to screen 2}`.  Now that I think about it (after a few hours of sleep), `{send to screen 1}` **&** `{send to screen 2}` would come even closer to simultaneity.  And another thought: if fine-grained calibration is important, you could use `strace` (with the `-tt` option, or equivalent) on both commands to see exactly when they ran, and compute the offset.

Comment: Thank you for thinking about this problem. Could you please elaborate on your proposed solution? I am not very experienced with Terminal.

Comment: I’m not experienced with Terminal or Screen either.  I was hoping that you had that part covered by [that other question that you referenced](http://superuser.com/questions/116743/send-command-to-screen/150988#150988); I was just addressing the Unix aspects.