# Screen fails to properly load when called with crontab

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, gnu-screen

#### What I'm doing

I've been migrating one setup to another, copying configuration and installing dependencies, I was about to be done until screen didn't work as intended.

I have a script that I keep runing on a detached screen that I initialize on boot, the setup is practically identical to the one on the old machine, still no luck

#### What I have:

- an Ubuntu 20.04 machine
- a bar.screenrc with:

```
screen sh /path/to/file/foo.sh
```

- a foo.sh with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.8
cd /path/to/file/
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5002 wsgi:app --log-level debug --error-logfile gunicorn.log
```

- a cronjob with:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/screen -c /path/to/file/bar.screenrc >> /path/to/file/cron.log 2>&1 -dmS API
```

#### The scenario

On reboot no new session appears, however, if I copy and paste the line (without the @reboot), it'll work as intended.

I tried changing the .screenrc to `/usr/bin/screen /usr/bin/sh /path/to/file/foo.sh` and this change does initiate a detached screen, but its not running the gunicorn instance

This exact same scenario works on the old setup and has worked on other projects of my own in the past

##### Disclaimer

I know things can be done with services instead of screen, this is out of the current scope of the project and this question.

Comment: Duplicate https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78017/running-screen-through-a-reboot-cron-job https://superuser.com/questions/918677/starting-script-in-screen-with-cron https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30266676/run-screen-and-command-crontab  probably others.

Comment: As much as a duplicate, not sure, the 2nd and 3rd don't offer much help, but it wasn't until the 4th answer on the 1st one that I found a workaround, not exactly a fix or explanation why this is not happening on my other server, but oh well.

I changed the crontab to be: 
`@reboot /usr/bin/screen -dmS API sh -c '/path/to/file/bar.screenrc;exec sh'`

And that was it, it spins a screen with two windows, one running gunicorn, the other one empty, no idea why this works but after 3 days of trying to figure it out, I'll let it slide